# No provider for CompilerFactory

Tags: angular, angular9

I have quite the same problem with this one, [NullInjectorError: No provier for CompilerFactory after updating to angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387960/nullinjectorerror-no-provier-for-compilerfactory-after-updating-to-angular-9).
And I tried the suggestion in the post to change from 
`platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` to `platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModule)`. However, I am getting a new error in the terminal as below:

```
  Argument of type 'typeof AppModule' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModuleFactory<unknown>'.
  Type 'typeof AppModule' is missing the following properties from type 'NgModuleFactory<unknown>': moduleType, create.
```

The version I am using is angular 9 and typescript 3.6.4

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?